# Why does <context:component-scan base-package="springmvc"/> result in 'No matching beans'?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am new to spring-mvc. Whenever I configure my spring mvc `servlet.xml` with the code `<context:component-scan base-package="springmvc"/>` it results in an error as seen in this screenshot here:

[image: screenshot]

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: So where's the structure of your java classes? It says that no beans match the `springmvc` package - is this really how your package is named?

Answer (score 0):

Try building the project. This error should resolve after you build your project.
 But you should have a package named 'springmvc' in your project's source.
Even if the error doesn't go after building the project and you have a package named 'springmvc' in your project's source, your program should work correctly.
I also face the same issue sometime in Spring Tool Suite(Eclipse), but my program runs fine.